# Privilege error while creating MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to execute the following trigger in the dev environment. This trigger works fine locally (local user does not have super privilege and log bin is enabled). Here is the trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `myschema`$$
CREATE
DEFINER=`user`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `myschema`.`roles_BEFORE_INSERT`
BEFORE INSERT ON `myschema`.`roles`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.role_id IS NULL) THEN
    -- Find max existed role id
    SELECT
      MAX(role_id) INTO @max_role_id
    FROM
      roles;
 
    IF (@max_role_id IS NULL) THEN
      -- Set first role id
      SET NEW.role_id = CONCAT('RID', '0001');
    ELSE
      -- Set next role id
      SET NEW.role_id = CONCAT(SUBSTR(@max_role_id, 1, 3), LPAD(SUBSTR(@max_role_id, 4) + 1, 4, '0'));
    END IF;
  END IF;
END$$
```

I am getting the following error while executing the above script in dev environment where I do not have access to check whether user has what privileges and log bin is enabled or not. Could you please tell me is there any way I can specify super privilege or setting the log bin enable query along with the above script itself. I am having a hard time as the issue is not reproducible in local environment. Any help is appreciated.

```
SQL State  : HY000
Error Code : 1419
Message    : You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled 
(you might want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone who has SUPER privilege must grant it to you, or create your trigger themselves.  It's the same kind of thing as Administrator priv on Windows or root priv on *nix.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will check that. In order to set log_bin_trust_function_creators too we need super privileges?

Answer (score 0):

To check current user grants:
login with user in mysql and

mysql> show grants;

to check supper user:

mysql>select user,host from mysql.user where super_priv='y';

to check bonlog:

mysql> show global variables like "log_bin";

Fix:
you can fix it by enabling log_bin_trust_function_creators

mysql> set global log_bin_trust_function_creators =ON;

read the official doc for more details.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_bin_trust_function_creators

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will go through this. Is there a way I can set log_bin_trust_function_creators to OFF or 0 locally. So that I can reproduce the issue.I have tried the same but it says 
mysql>  set global log_bin_trust_function_creators =OFF;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Comment: Once you change the setting fire again to confirm the change.
mysql> show global variables like "log_bin_trust_function_creators ";